# How to improve the efficiency of remove all (2000) TestFlight testers when using Pilot

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-pilot

I need to replace all (2000) TestFLight testers on every new TestFLight version of my app. So I have to remove all (2000) of them first, then I can import the new testers.

Recently, I try to use Pilot to assist me to do the "remove" job. But I found that when I give Pilot a bunch of testers, it will search one, delete one, search another one, delete another one, which needs too much time. As my test, it will need almost 4 hours to remove 2000 testers, which is not acceptable. So here I want to ask how to improve the efficiency of this remove job? Or am I use Pilot in a wrong way?

The command I use:

```
fastlane pilot remove some@test.com another@test.com xxx -a com.xx.xx -u <my email account>
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is actually not posible.

I was looking on the source code, and seems only you could remove one by one, which as you told is awful slow.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/pilot/lib/pilot/tester_manager.rb

The strange thing, it's on `fastlane pilot remove --help`.
Seems to be an option `-c, --testers_file_path STRING Path to a CSV file of testers (PILOT_TESTERS_FILE)`, have you tried?

If doesn't work, maybe you could do a PR with some changes to be able to get an array of mails to remove/add testers.

Comment: so five years after this comment I tried this. Even though the `testers_file_path` is documented it doesn't appear to be implemented at all. The only option seems to be to run it one-by-one. It's going to take about 24 hours to run :-(

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution for Pilot per say, but it looks like you used Pilot purely to speed up the removal process. I just had to remove over 500 TestFlight testers from an app in App Store Connect (to facilitate an app transfer). It was painfully slow selecting each one to remove them, then I discovered you could select all at once.

Note: This was in Safari 12.1.1

1. Go into Edit Mode on the TestFlight tester list you want to remove
   from
2. Tap the first row to select that tester
3. Scroll all the way to the bottom of the tester list
4. Hold Shift and tap the last row and all rows will be selected
5. Tap delete at the top to remove them all

Hope this helps someone save a lot of time!